# what is the meaning of "fuller revelation" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "fuller revelation" in this context?

> There may have been—in fact, there probably was—a true psychic origin
>   to these phenomena, but they had developed in a soil of narrow bigoted
>   theology, which was bound to bring them to ruin. Even Swedenborg's
>   religious system was too narrow to receive the full undistorted gifts of
>   the spirit, so one can imagine what they became when contracted within
>   the cramped limits of a Scottish church, where every truth must be
>   shorn or twisted until it corresponds with some fantastic text. The new
>   good wine will not go into the old narrow bottles. **Had there been a
>   fuller revelation, then doubtless other messages would have been
>   received in other fashions which would have presented the matter in its
>   just proportions, and checked one spiritual gift by others**. But there was
>   no development save towards chaos. Some of the teaching received
>   could not be reconciled with orthodoxy, and was therefore obviously of
>   the devil. Some of the sensitives condemned others as heretics. Voice
>   was raised against voice. Worst of all, some of the chief speakers
>   became convinced themselves that their own speeches were diabolical.

Answer (score 1):

Context is everything. Two days ago, when you asked about this paragraph on ELU,  you cited its source there -- *A History of Spiritualism* (1926) by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. It may help to know that when it came to spiritualism, psychic phenomena, and other supposed aspects of the supernatural, ACD was a credulous dupe. The first line of your excerpt reads, "There may have been  -- in fact, there probably was -- a true psychic origin to these phenomena.

Well, no. There almost certainly wasn't a "true psychic origin" in this case because there's no such thing as a true psychic origin to anything. But we have to know what "phenomena" ACD was talking about, and what he was talking about was the reports of a spate of what we would call today "speaking in tongues" in Scottish churches in the 1830s. This is the act of babbling nonsense syllables by certain church-goers who claim to be inspired by the Holy Spirit. Actually in the cases ACD notes, some people spoke in tongues and others spoke intelligibly about religious topics, but they all claimed divine inspiration.

The result was chaos in those churches. The intelligible bits sometimes couldn't be reconciled with scripture. Some of the congregation accused the speakers of diabolical motivation. Some of the speakers themselves thought their speech was inspired by the devil. ACD says all this might have been avoided

> Had there been a **fuller revelation**

in other words, had there been a guiding divine communication beyond the bald claims of the inspired speakers that they were divinely inspired, things might have been more orderly and less accusatory.